# How to set zoom step in D3JS v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to achieve consistent behavior between zooming in the view by buttons and mouse scroll. While I am able to specify the zoom step (0.5) using buttons (by calling zoom.scaleTo), I am wondering how I can do the same when using the mouse scroll. Should I somehow do this in "zoom" event callback, and there try to modify the event transform? Or should I capture wheel event's and there try to manually invoke d3.zoom functions? I'd like the mouse scroll to change scale every 0.5 step and maitain the center point of zoom to be the mouse location. Do you have any suggestions what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 600)
.attr("height", 600)
.call(zoom);

var mainContainer = svg.append("g");
```

please check with JSFiddle example i thinks you can help with this
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/manish1226/2eL8z8xa/)

Comment: I see you've set here the scale extent, but that does not guarantee that the scale will change every 0.2 step on scroll. I want to have situation like so:I have initial position, scale = 1. Now when I click button zoom in, I can do it four times (every 0.2) to reach 0.2 limit. I wan the same for scroll. From starting position I would like to be able to zoom in by scroll only four times.